# Mac OS, console application. performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c, macos, selector, delay, performselector

I created a simple singleton and run method in it:

```
- (void)run {

    static int times = 0;
    NSLog(@"times = %d", times++);

    [self performSelector:@selector(run) withObject:nil afterDelay:MIN_DELAY];
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. It is executed only once.

But if I replace `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with `performSelector:` then it will be called a lot of times (but I need a delay between calls).

So why method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` doesn't work? And can I use this method at all?

Answer (score 3):

Calls to `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` require a run loop. Console applications do not, by default, pass control into the run loop ever. For more info, search for NSRunLoop.

Comment: What's the alternative in that scenario?

Comment: Use GCD. Look up `dispatch_after`.

Comment: Thanks! Just found it and that does indeed to the job.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> This method registers with the runloop of its current context, and depends on that runloop being run on a regular basis to perform correctly.

You have no runloop. Ipso facto, this method does not perform correctly for you.

(Creating and starting a runloop is one of the things that calling `UIApplicationMain` does, but of course you are never calling it.)